# Analysis Services database restore fatal error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

Fatal error occurs when restoring AS database

Fatal internal error.
 (Microsoft.AnalysisServices)

---

Расположение программы:

в Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)
   в Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesClient.Restore(String file, String databaseName, Boolean allowOverwrite, ICollection locations, RestoreSecurity security, String password, String dbStorageLocation)
   в Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Restore(String file, String databaseName, Boolean allowOverwrite, RestoreLocation[] locations, RestoreSecurity security, String password, String dbStorageLocation)
   в Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs.RestoreDialog.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   в Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   в Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForOlap(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   в Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   в Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)

Please suggest which way to dig

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem is different versions of SSAS. The primary is SP2, the one I want to deploy to is just 2008 R2